# Stale custom hook state property on callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook in my React app that exposes a function (`hookFn`) to calculate a `value`. Once the value has been updated (state change, triggering useEffect), the hook alerts the app via a callback function. Here's the issue: in my callback function, I want to be able to access the value via `hook.value`, but it seems to be stale! Even though I know the value state has been updated!

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-payne-bwp6j5?file=/src/App.js:0-910

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const hook = useCustomHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    hook.hookFn(hookCallback);
  }, []);

  function hookCallback(value) {
    console.log({givenValue: value, hookValue: hook.value});
  }

  return "See console for output";
}

function useCustomHook() {
  const callbackRef = useRef(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("initial value");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (callbackRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current(value);
    }
  }, [value]);

  function hookFn(callbackFn) {
    callbackRef.current = callbackFn;
    setValue("value set in hookFn");
  }

  return { hookFn, value };
}
```

FYI: in my actual app, the hook is for searching, which may call the callback function multiple times as more search results become available.

Is there any way to ensure `hook.value` will be valid? Or is it bad practice for a hook to expose a state variable in general?

Comment: Do you have to use `setInterval` in your actual app? or is it just for an example?

Comment: @Jae Yes--it is a search function that could be expensive so I want it to run asynchronously. In the final version of the app it will probably search both locally cached and ajax-fetched data, but I still might use setTimeout so it runs async from the start. Does that sound like bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `hook.value` is stale because `hook` is stale when I access it from `hookCallback`. Each time there is a state change within my custom hook, `useCustomHook` will generate a new object.

The complex solution, then, is to to create a `ref` for `hook` and keep it up to date in `useEffect`. But then I have to make sure I wait for that `useEffect` to run before accessing `hookRef.current.value`... Here's my attempt to make this work: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-shirley-0r7k47?file=/src/App.js

However, a better solution: **don't mix React states and manual callbacks.** Instead, just watch for state changes in a `useEffect`, like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const hook = useCustomHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    hook.hookFn();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hook.value) console.log({ hookValue: hook.value });
  }, [hook.value]);

  return "See console for output";
}

function useCustomHook() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("initial value");

  function hookFn(callbackFn) {
    setValue("value set in hookFn");
  }

  return { hookFn, value };
}
```

Notice the code is simplified, and there's no need for concern about states being out-of-sync.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have pretty much answered you own question. Alternatively, you could pass your callback function as input to your custom hook.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const hook = useCustomHook(hookCallback);

  useEffect(() => {
    hook.setNewValue();
  },[])

  function hookCallback(value) {
    console.log({
      givenValue: value,
      hookValue: hook.value, // Why is this stale??
      areIdentical: value === hook.value // Should be true!!!
    });
  }

  return <h1>See console for output</h1>;
}

function useCustomHook(callback) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("initial value");

  useEffect(() => {
      callback(value);
  }, [value]);

  function setNewValue(callbackFn) {
    setValue("value set in hookFn");

    setTimeout(() => {
      setValue("value set in setTimeout");
    }, 100);
  }

  return { setNewValue, value };
}
```